# Adding default maven build configuration on Jenkins

Tags: maven, hudson, jenkins, pom.xml

I am setting up a CI system using Jenkins for Maven based projects. I was wondering whether there is a way to specify a build configuration which would be common for all the projects deployed on Jenkins.

For instance, I want all the projects to generate JavaDoc's hence I require the  *maven-javadoc-plugin*  in maven pom. As I understand, this can't be added to the **settings.xml** file. And I don't have access to the super pom. And editing the super pom isn't a good idea anyways.

What is the best way to add a common build profile for all the projects?

Comment: Take a look at maven profiles: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: @Dag I did have a look at the link you mentioned earlier. But it only provides information on how to set generic properties/settings. I am thinking in line of setting a generic '<build> </build>' for all project.s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corporate POM, that's what I was looking for.